# Calculate angle from matrix transform

Tags: c#, wpf, math, matrix

I have following line of code:
I have applied few rotation to the rectangle at without knowing values (of how many degrees). Now I want to get Rotation or angle of element in 2D.

```
Rectangle element = (Rectangle)sender;
MatrixTransform xform = element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
Matrix matrix = xform.Matrix;
third.Content = (Math.Atan(matrix.M21 / matrix.M22)*(180/Math.PI)).ToString();

and the matrix is like following
|M11 M12 0|
|M21 M22 0|
|dx  dy  1|  which is Transformation Matrix I guess !!
```

This does not seems to be correct value.
I want to get angles in **0 to 360 degrees**

Comment: I guess it's a transformation matrix.

Comment: yes it's Transformation Matrix and IT's type of MatrixTransform in C#.
I want to get Angle after Transformation is applied.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var x = new Vector(1, 0);
Vector rotated = Vector.Multiply(x, matrix);
double angleBetween = Vector.AngleBetween(x, rotated);
```

The idea is:

1. We create a tempvector (1,0)
2. We apply the matrix transform on the vector and get a rotated temp vector
3. We calculate the angle between the original and the rotated temp vector

You can play around with this:

```
[TestCase(0,0)]
[TestCase(90,90)]
[TestCase(180,180)]
[TestCase(270,-90)]
[TestCase(-90, -90)]
public void GetAngleTest(int angle, int expected)
{
    var matrix = new RotateTransform(angle).Value;
    var x = new Vector(1, 0);
    Vector rotated = Vector.Multiply(x, matrix);
    double angleBetween = Vector.AngleBetween(x, rotated);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected,(int)angleBetween);
}
```

Comment: Thanks people for instant reply.

Answer (score 11):

**FOR FUTURE REFERENCE:**

This will give you the rotation angle of a transformation matrix in radians:

```
var radians = Math.Atan2(matrix.M21, matrix.M11);
```

and you can convert the radians to degrees if you need:

```
var degrees = radians * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answers will be in radians, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/c14fd846-19b9-4e8a-ba6c-0b885b424439/.

So simply convert the values back to degrees using the following:

```
double deg = angle * (180.0 / Math.PI);
```